# Add schema to a Dataset[Row] in Java

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark and trying to explore Spark structured streaming. I will be consuming messages from Kafka(nested JSON), filter these messages based on certain conditions on the JSON attribute. Every message satisfying the filter should then be pushed to Cassandra.

I have read the documentation on spark Cassandra connector 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark
.readStream()
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
.option("subscribe", "topic1")
.load() 

df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

I only need a few of the many attributes present in this nested JSON. How do I apply a schema on top of it, so that I can use sparkSQL for filtering?

For the sample JSON, I need to persist name, age, experience, hobby_name,hobby_experience for players whose sum of playing frequency is more than 5.

```
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": "24",
    "gender": "male",
    "hobbies": [{
        "name": "Tennis",
        "experience": 5,
        "places": [{
            "city": "London",
            "frequency": 4
        }, {
            "city": "Sydney",
            "frequency": 3
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am relatively new to Spark, please forgive if this is a repeat. Also, I am looking for a solution in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your schema like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataTypes, StructField, StructType};

StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
    DataTypes.createStructField("name",  DataTypes.StringType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("gender", DataTypes.StringType, true),
    DataTypes.createStructField("hobbies", DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("experience", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("places", DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("city", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("frequency", DataTypes.IntegerType, true)
        }), true)
    }), true)
});
```

And then use the schema to create your dataframe as needed:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, from_json};

df.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data"))
  .select(
    col("data.name").as("name"),
    col("data.hobbies.name").as("hobbies_name"))
```